# Finding real world distance using an image

Tags: opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I am working on a project where I need to figure out real world distance of an object with reference to a fixed point using an image.

I have detected the object in a 2D image, using `SURF`. My object is inside a box now. What will give me the position of the centroid of the object. How can I use this to find out the real word distance?

If I plan to incorporate stereo vision, triangulating the centroid of the object, what is the difference between the distance I obtain here and in the previous method?

Comment: Do you know the real-world dimensions and depth of the box, and the dimensions of your object? If so, the problem is tractable. Otherwise, it's not possible to know object depth from a single image. You will have to use stereo vision.

Answer (score 1):

On a single image, probably the best starting point to learn about estimating metrical properties is Antonio Criminisi's work (2000 vintage, but still very relevant): http://www.cs.illinois.edu/~dhoiem/courses/vision_spring10/sources/criminisi00.pdf